# Copy files to absolute path using gulp

Tags: macos, gulp

I'm trying to write a gulp task that'll copy all the files from the development folder into an apache folder.

```
// Copies current file to the local www folder
gulp.task('copy', function(){
   return gulp.src('**/*')
              .pipe(gulp.dest('~/Sites/foldername')); 
});
```

But gulp creates a `~` folder in the current directory and ends up copying the files to `./~/Sites/foldername`.

How do I make gulp treat my path as an absolute path rather than a relative path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gulp (or node) is not able to resolve `~`, hardcode the full home path or use a utility function that gets you the home path for current user.